# Making UIButton content fully tappable with clear background color

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a set of `UIButtons` where each label is just a number. On each button of them, I set the background color to clear, there is no `UIImage` set.

The problem is those buttons are only tappable on their label which makes it hard to tap.

I checked around for this problem and some solutions were to:

- change the content insets: `button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-50, -50, -50, -50)` -> didn't change a thing
- subclass UIButton and override `pointInside` -> didn't work, `pointInside` was never reached when tapping on the button but outside the label.

I'm just surprised there is no easy solution for such a normal use case.
I need the background clear as I am using those buttons for today's extension.

Any idea how I could do it?

EDIT:

Here is a [sample project](https://github.com/nico75005/TestClearBackgroundButton) where I reproduced the problem.

It seems it's linked to static cell in a today extension as it's okay with static cell in a view controller within the app.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself." - please add code and possibly a sample project to your question

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Apply a `backgroundColor` of `UIColor(white:0.000, alpha:0.020)`. The human eye cannot see this color — it appears completely transparent in the Today widget — but the button background is now tappable.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot. Do you know why it behaves like this with Today widget?

Comment: We are not in charge of how hit-testing works in the Today environment, so it probably has to do with that. Presumably the button background fails the hit-test if it is clear, just as would be true of a plain UIView. So I solved it in the same way I would if this were a plain UIView. I suppose we could figure out the details if we really had to. Personally I prefer to solve the problem and walk away. :)